# Is there any support for using Facebook SDK (app events to be specific) in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, facebook-sdk-4.0

I would like to add the Facebook app-events to my Flutter project: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/android https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/ios

May I know should Flutter users implement their plugin to use the Facebook features?

Answer (score 4):

You can integrate Facebook app events using this package called [facebook_app_events(null-safety)](https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_app_events).

**Android Setup:**

**STEP 1:** goto `your_project\android\app\src\main\res\values` create a new file called `strings.xml` **(if you don't have any already)**
In the `strings.xml` file just paste this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="facebook_app_id">[APP_ID]</string>
</resources>
```

Don't forget to replace `[APP_ID]` with the original `APP_ID` you got from [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/) **e.g**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="facebook_app_id">1234567890</string>
</resources>
```

**STEP 2:** goto `your_project\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml` and paste this under your app `<application>` open tag

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

*Android setup done.*

**iOS setup:**

goto `one_app\ios\Runner\info.plist` file and add

- If your code does not have `CFBundleURLTypes`, add the following just
  before the final `</dict>` element:

```xml
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
  <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>fb[APP_ID]</string>
  </array>
  </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>[APP_ID]</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>[APP_NAME]</string>
```

- If your code already contains `CFBundleURLTypes`, insert the
  following:

```xml
<array>
 <dict>
 <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
 <array>
   <string>fb[APP_ID]</string>
 </array>
 </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>[APP_ID]</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>[APP_NAME]</string>
```

*iOS setup is done*

NOTE: don't forget to add the package to your pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  facebook_app_events: ^0.12.0
```

Comment: Very detailed answer! Thanks a lot! Is there anyway to know whether we have successfully implemented facebook app event or not ?

Answer (score 2):

So far, you can find the [facebook_app_events](https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_app_events) package at pub.dev which is very good. Note that (at the time of writing this answer) the package doesn't support null safety, so you should use it with Dart 2.11 and lower.

There are no official packages from Facebook yet.